# SQL SELECT Query based on yes or no questions

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I have two question sets. One is Yes or No questions. Based on this question's answers I need to display another set of questions.
For this I have added a question code for Yes or No questions.
and for the second set questions given these question codes to identify for displaying this question or not.

```
For example 
Y/N questions - Question Code
1.AAAAAAAA - AAA
2.BBBBBBBB - BBB
3.CCCCCCCC - CCC

Second Set questions - Question Code
1.XXXXXXXX - AAA && BBB
2.YYYYYYYY - AAA && !BBB
3.ZZZZZZZZ - AAA && !BBB && CCC
```

So second set question number 1 will display only if Y/N question number 1 and 2 answer Yes.
Question number 2 will display only if Y/N question number 1 answer Yes and number 2 answer No.
Question number 3 will display only if Y/N question number 1 answer Yes, number 2 answer No and number 3 answer Yes.

How can we write query for displaying second set of questions to display based on the Y/N question answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to normalize your tables.  Your 2nd table's 2nd column should really be an associative (many-to-many) table between the first and second set of questions.  With that in place your query would be much simpler.

Comment: Create a question table Question (id, question) and a related question table RQuestion (id, question_id, related[bool]).  And from there it should be just tweaking the tables and your sql. (I've not actually got this working but it doesn't seem all that difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

Putting this logic inside the database is in my opinion a bad design approach. Instead I would query the results to your logic layer and analyse the results. From these results you could create a new query with the next questions.

With all the logic inside your query statement it makes it very hard to maintain.

Comment: I concur, otherwise you'll have to start messing around with stored procedures.

Comment: How to write a select query to display second set of question based on the Y/N questions?